# Connecting PHP to SQL Server with Azure Active Directory

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to connect to a SQL Database with PHP and Azure Active Directory. I have follow Microsoft steps to connect but the application returns unable to connect. Just for reference I am running PHP 7.4.9 and I have the correct PHP extension installed because I have been able to connect to my Local SQL Server and a Network SQL Server.

```
$azureServer = "********.crm.dynamics.com,5558";
$azureDatabase = "************";
$azureUsername = "***********@**********.onmicrosoft.com";
$azurePassword = "**********";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$azureDatabase,
                        "UID"=>$azureUsername,
                        "PWD"=>$azurePassword,
                        "Authentication"=>'ActiveDirectoryPassword'
                       );

try 
{ 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($azureServer, $connectionInfo);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Could not connect with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword.<p></p>";
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully with Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword.<p></p>";
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: you forgot to show what it shows print_r(sqlsrv_errors());

Comment: That is the issue. I am not receiving an error. I can use the credentials and access the database in SSMS Sql Server Management Studio  but, the same credentials do not work in php.

Comment: if you run 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($azureServer, $connectionInfo); then there must be anything in  $e->getMessage() or sqlsrv_errors(). If not - read apache acces.log or error.log or php error.log.

Comment: sqlsrv_connect - returns  connection resource. If a connection cannot be successfully opened, false is returned. Check what it returns in your example

Comment: Checked the php and apache error logs there is nothing return there

Comment: var_dump( $conn = sqlsrv_connect($azureServer, $connectionInfo) ); - what will show ??

Comment: var_dump returns boolean false

Comment: Same with `var_dump(sqlsrv_errors())`, is it empty or null. Do you have PHP error reporting turned on, too?